# Renaming Project files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

I have a project that my team has been working on for some time (Project name = 'X'). We use TFS as source control.

This project contains a bunch of projects in it (eg. X.Cloud, X.Database, X.WebApi, etc..). We have recently re-branded and re-named the project. I would like the project to no longer be named X, but the new name (say Y) so that my main project is called Y and its sub-projects are named Y.Cloud, Y.Database, Y.WebApi, etc..

I require the system files to be renamed. When I just update the project the files locally will still be named project X and not Y. I want the system files to also be called Y.

I have looked online and attempted the renaming but it failed catastrophically. I wonder if one of you have maybe done this before and have a good guide of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Team Project rename has just been implemented on VS Online:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2015/04/24/team-project-rename-available-on-vs-online.aspx

And should also come in TFS 2013 Update 5:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-update5-vs.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am going to follow this and will mark it as correct if all goes well :)

Comment: Going through the article I realize that this is for renaming the project. I am talking about the project files themselves (ie The files that are on my computer). I am going to update the question to highlight this better.